# Pop up Modal component in react on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a customized login modal pop up on button click in react.

My code:

```
// ModalWrap.js
      <section>     
         <div className="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog" style={{maxWidth: "420px"}}>
              .....
             
             </div>
           </div>
        </section>
```

In my Index.js file I'm trying to call this modal
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

```
<Modal show={isOpen} onHide={hideModal}>
    <ModalWrap/>
</Modal>
```

But the problem here, which you can see that I have to call my `ModalWrap` inside `Modal` component, Is there any other way I can achieve it. I don't want to call the modal again inside my `Index.js`.

Comment: Why must you wrap `ModalWrap` component within another `Modal` component?

Comment: Please check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Comment: If I don't wrap inside Modal, It won't work like it's supposed to work

Comment: What does that mean though? Is there an error? Can you share the entire `ModalWrap` component so we may see how it's mounted and opened/closed?

Comment: Are you looking for something `Modal.confirm(...)` method instead of `<Modal><Modal.Header />.....</Modal>`?

Comment: I have changed my `ModalWrap` Code. This is how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass props there instead of defining them inside ModalWrap.
So in index.js:

```
    <ModalWrap isOpen={isOpen} hideModal={hideModal}/>
```

and inside ModalWrap component just do:

```
     <Modal show={props.isOpen} onHide={props.hideModal} dialogClassName="my-modal">
       // rest of code
     </Modal>
```

Comment: what if I'm not using Modal component inside my ModalWrap, I'm using `div`. since I'm using react- bootstrap

Comment: @naive_user but there is modal in react-bootstrap, here it is - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/ , you can reuse that. Why do you want to make something that is already done?

Comment: Because, customization is very difficult if i'm using Modal of react-bootstrap

Comment: If you want to have a div inside ModalWrap, you would have to add additional classes and styling to it so it will be only visible when show is true, react-bootstrap modal has it already by default

Comment: I have changed my ModalWrap Code. This is how it looks like

Comment: I can use Modal but I'm not able to change the border radius. If I can change border radius than it will work